# Magento FedEx not working

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.7, fedex

I am really stuck with the Magento-FedEx integration process and cannot proceed further.I have filled up all the valid data for FedEx at the backend and not able to implement the same at the frontend.Its giving me the default error message that FedEx is unavailable.It would be great if anyone could help me out with this.Please find the screenshot of the issue below.In addition is there any table in database where the filled up details are getting inserted,if yes it would be great if I can know that too.

I am using the built in FedEx shipping for magento and have given the following details at the backend side for implementation.Yes,I'm using a web service for FedEx.

## Is there anything else I need to do for this?Or else, what could be the reason for the          issue.

## There was a problem with the weights of the product created and hence after making it correct the error message is not shown now.But currently its showing that, no quotes are available for the product.Is there anything else I need to change in order to tackle this issue.

[image][image]

Comment: you have to provide more information. is this an extension? did you generated the meter number with password and key to transact with fedex? is this extension working with api-deprecated- or webservices?